# Uncaught TypeError: document.getElementsByClassName(...).addEventListener is not a function

Tags: javascript, event-handling, dom-events

I need to listen for clicks on `<input/>` elements.
This is my code

```
<script>
    document.getElementsByClassName("form-control").addEventListener("click", function(e){
      alert("Listener added");
    });
</script>
```

But I'm getting this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: document.getElementsByClassName(...).addEventListener is not a function
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

The reason why you are getting this error is because getElementsByClassName returns an array of elements but you need to have a single element in order to add an event listener. If you want to add event listener to all elements, you can simply loop through the array as shown below.

```
document.getElementsByClassName("form-control").forEach(element => {
  element.onclick = event => {
    alert("Listener added");
  }
});
```

If you want to add event listener to a specific element, you can simply access it by indexing the array.

```
document.getElementsByClassName("form-control")[0].addEventListener("click", function(e){
  alert("Listener added");
});
```

You can also use ids for specific elements in order to access them more easily.